# I want to retrieve records from a List and update a DE, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, wsproxy

I tried retrieve the records from my list and then try "updateitem" with Data Extension inside

but it's not working

```
<script runat="server">
 
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
 
    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
 
 try {
 
 var res = api.retrieve("ListSubscriber", 
    ["SubscriberKey"],
    {
        Property: "ListID",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "xxxx"
    }
);
   
   var options = {
 SaveOptions: [
  {
   PropertyName: 'SubscriberKey',
   SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'
  }
 ]
};
   var result = api.updateItem('Subscriber', {
 CustomerKey: "XXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
 
}, options);
 Write(Stringify(res));
  
 } catch(error) {
  Write(Stringify(error));
 }
 
</script>
```

I would like to know, what is wrong in the body of my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this all of the code?  Where are you retrieving the SubscriberKey value from your first retrieve?  Not sure why you're using WSProxy, either.  There are base functions for interacting with [Subscribers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_subscriberFunctions.html) and [Lists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_listSubscribersUpsert.html):

Comment: Yes, its all the code, I'm using WSProxy because I have more than 2.500 subscribers to retrieve